# getting last two digits from numeric in R

Tags: r, numeric, digits

I need to get last two digits from a number saved in numeric type and save it another in variable for example:
a=1945
it takes last two digits and place it in b
b=45

Comment: You should show your own effort.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the modulus operator `%%`

```
a <- 1945
b <- 1945 %% 100 
#b = 45
```

Comment: This doesn't work for numbers with a zero in the second to last positions. For example 2002 %% 100 returns 2, not 02.

Answer (score 9):

If you're using years, probably best (and what I use for this) is `sprintf` combined with `%%`, which will convert the number to a string, but will preserve `1905` as `05` instead of `5` (may be preferable depending on your application):

```
sprintf('%02d', 1999:2010 %% 100)
# [1] "99" "00" "01" "02" "03" "04" "05" "06" "07" "08" "09" "10"
```

Coming back to add that perhaps a more "proper" approach, in the sense of properly leveraging the date/time utilities in base R, might be to convert first to a `Date` and then use `format`:

```
format(.Date(365.25 * (1999:2010 - 1969.75)), '%y')
# [1] "99" "00" "01" "02" "03" "04" "05" "06" "07" "08" "09" "10"
```

The `1969.75` re-centers the years around 1970 (see `.Date(0L)`), but we need to re-re-center this to account for leap years.

Even this, however, will only be correct for about 400 years (or maybe as many as 1600?) due to leap centuries... for such a wide range of dates, the way forward with `Date`s is:

```
format(as.Date(sprintf('%d-01-01', 1999:2010)), '%y')
```

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
a <- 1945
b <- a - round(a, -2)
b
[1] 45
```

This is assuming there are no decimals, of course.

This has the side benefit of preserving sign...

```
a <- -1945
b <- a - round(a, -2)
b
[1] -45
```

Comment: Due to R rounding evens differently to odds, this only works if the second to last digit is in 0:4. e.g. `1966 - round(1966, -2)` is `-34`.

Answer (score 1):

you can directly use `substr()`, it it detects and converts `numeric` to `string`. Need to convert back to numeric. Ex :

```
num = c(1112, 1113)
trim = as.numeric(substr(num, nchar(num[1])-1, nchar(num[1])))
```

Comment: just thought of this, best answer IMO

Comment: Some unexpected (to me) behavior of this:

num = c(10.55, 0.00)
trim = as.numeric(substr(num, nchar(num[1])-1, nchar(num[1])))

Returns NA for the 0.00

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, this allows for tailing zeros after a decimal place. This also does not require calculating length of the string/number.

`stringr` has the str_sub function and `f_pad_right` comes from the `numform` package.

This gets the last digit from a number:

```
> library(stringr)
> library(numform)
> str_sub(f_pad_right(as.character(1.20), pad.char = 0,width = 4), - 1, - 1)
[1] "0"
```

Last two digits:

```
> str_sub(f_pad_right(as.character(1.20), pad.char = 0,width = 4), - 2, - 1)
[1] "20"
```

Answering the OP question:

```
> str_sub(f_pad_right(as.character(1945), pad.char = 0,width = 4), - 2, - 1)
[1] "45"
```